# angularjs removing special characters in dynamic form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use angularjs dynamic form elements but when I type something in inputs, there are appearing many special characters `[]"":` and `field, value` .etc in textarea, I just want to see in textarea  what I wrote in inputs ,

this is what I am working on it http://plnkr.co/edit/JbjqjAoQ3odBhXF1a13r?p=preview

sorry for my poor english,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Chris Story says is correct. You are trying to model the *text* value of the `<textarea>` to an array of objects, `inputs`

If you are just trying to display the results like it seems, a `<textarea>` is not the way to go. You can display them in a simple list, like this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="input in inputs">{{input.field}} = {{input.value}}</li>
</ul>
```

> EDIT

To display it in a `<textarea>`, you will need to store the list as string to use. This can be done by appending each item into a single string each time there is a change to an input value using `ng-change`.

Change the inputs to utilize the ng-change:

```
<div ng-repeat="input in inputs">
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.field" ng-change="inputChanged()" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="input.value" ng-change="inputChanged()" />
    <button ng-click="removeInput($index); inputChanged()">Remove</button>
</div>
```

And create the function that is called to maintain the string:

```
$scope.inputChanged = function() {
  $scope.listString = "";
  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.inputs.length; i++) {
    var field = $scope.inputs[i].field;
    var value = $scope.inputs[i].value;
    $scope.listString += field + " = " + value + "; ";
  }
}
```

And finally, use this `$scope.listString` in the `<textarea>`:

```
<textarea rows="22" cols="55" ng-model="listString"></textarea>
```

I have forked your Plunkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NzimXIaBuohIJHKq0058?p=preview)

The behavior does not make much sense from a UX perspective, but this seems to match your requirement. An option that might make sense is to add `disabled="true"` to the `<textarea>` so it can not be edited.

Comment: thx for answer it's working fine but I need to display results in textarea ,,

Comment: @AydIn are you going to have the textarea disabled? Or did you somehow want the user to be able to change the values in the textarea?

Comment: thank you very much ,,, it's exactly what I want... you are the best

Comment: but it's not removing the content in textarea when I click the Remove button

Comment: You're right. The remove button needs to also make this call to`inputChanged()`. It should look like this `<button ng-click="removeInput($index); inputChanged()">Remove</button>`. Updated the Plunkr

Comment: brettvd I need your help again :) I have added sortable option and it's working fine but When I drag the inputs,can not change the position in the textarea

this is plunker 
http://plnkr.co/edit/TT7wpZhrgcmp61N4KNHP?p=preview

Comment: It looks like you are using the bare jquery-ui sortable functionality. This means it's not maintaining the list as you want. You should use an Angular sortable option, like the one found in Angular-ui here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable Then use the callback functions there to call the `$scope.inputChanged()` function to update the text for the textarea

Comment: brettvd this is my last question :) I added $index option in this code but I couldn't add these numbers in textarea ,,, There is always "undefined" in numbers area,,, how can I insert numbers in textarea when I checked "add numbers" ..

plunker url;
http://plnkr.co/edit/TT7wpZhrgcmp61N4KNHP?p=preview,,,,

Comment: It looks like you don't _quite_ understand how `ng-model` works. `ng-model` is used for two-way data-binding, which means binding user input in `<input>` options like text, checkboxes, selects, etc. An `ng-model` on a `<div>` doesn't make sense. Also, another thing to point out is that the `{{ }}` Angular format you are using is equivalent to using `ng-bind`, which is one-way binding from javascript code to the front-end view. The best solution for your situation is really just to use the loop index `i`. You can use the built-in `$index` if you really want to, but it's not really worth it

Comment: I just start to use angularjs :) and thanks it's working ,,,, is there a way to show or hide numbers when I click the checkbox?

Comment: Add that `$scope.inputChanged()` function call to an `ng-change` on the checkbox. In `inputChanged()` only print out the number if `$scope.checked` is true

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are rendering {{inputs}} and inputs is an Array.

Comment: Second this. If you'd like the key and value to be speficiable, do something like this: